# How to redirect user to different urls based on verified or not verified

Tags: angular, url, parameters

I want to display username in  url link when user is verified otherwise I want display only userid

I have this routes in routing modules.ts
`{

    path: 'user-survey/:user_id/:user_name',
    canActivate : [AuthWebGuard],
    component: SurveyComponent
},`
`{
    path: 'favorite-world-survey',
    canActivate : [AuthWebGuard],
    component: SurveyComponent
  },`

this is my HTML page where I want to make condition  to redirect user

`<span *ngIf="!isUserSurveyList; else other_content">
                        <a *ngIf="!(this.commonService.authUser()==survey.user_id.email)"
                           routerLink="/user-survey/{{survey.user_id._id}}/{{survey.user_id.name}}"  class="a_link">
                           <p>
                              {{ survey.user_id.name }}
                              <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color: green; font-size: 30px;"
                                 *ngIf="survey.user_id.verifystatus"></i>
                           </p>
                        </a>
                         <a *ngIf="(this.commonService.authUser()==survey.user_id.email)" routerLink="/profile"
                           class="a_link">
                           <p>
                              {{ survey.user_id.name }}
                              <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style=" color: green; font-size: 30px;"
                                 *ngIf="survey.user_id.verifystatus"></i>
                           </p>
                        </a>
                     </span>`

`http://Address:4200/#/user-survey/5a7d5f351d3a5d4eb21feb02?type=1`

Is it possible ?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set your route config as

```
{  
    path: 'user-survey/:user_id/:user_name',
    canActivate : [AuthWebGuard],
    component: SurveyComponent
}
```

Send the username along with user id in the routerLink

```
[routerLink]="['/user-survey', survey.user_id.id, theUserName]"
```

In the component extract the username just as you were extracting `user_id`

For example:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe( params =>
        console.log(params['user_name']);
    )
}
```

**Edit**

If your route can and cannot have the user name in it then set two route configs, one with the username parameter, one without it.

```
[
    {  
        path: 'user-survey/:user_id/:user_name',
        canActivate : [AuthWebGuard],
        component: SurveyComponent
    }

    {  
        path: 'user-survey/:user_id',
        canActivate : [AuthWebGuard],
        component: SurveyComponent
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me  try with it

Comment: Should I write this way 
`routerLink="/user-survey/{{survey.user_id._id}}/{{name}}"`
or 
`routerLink="/user-survey/{{survey.user_id._id}}/{{survey.user_id.name}}"`

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga whatever holds the `username` value

Comment: Also, you might want to prefer the following notation:
`<a [routerLink]="['/user-survey', survey.user_id.id, theUserName]" [queryParams]="{type: 5}"> ... </a>`

You get 1) consistency between [routerLink] and [queryParams] inputs and 2) better handling of relative routes (may not be useful here but still).

Comment: ok then this one is right because if I am fetching userid like : survey.user_id.id then name: `survey.user_id.name`  `routerLink="/user-survey/{{survey.user_id._id}}/{{survey.user_id.name}}`

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga yeah, also use the notation as suggested in a comment above

Comment: but here I want to make condition for verified and not verified, if user is verified then I want to display name if not then only id.

Comment: I have already a condition for verified user, if user is verified then we showing checked mark so based on that I am trying to make condition.

Comment: Yes,  already I have set two routes for that but in the view page I am facing some issue, I am not able to make proper condition.

Comment: Are you there ?